# What's causing my <select> box to flicker when selected?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm using Angular 1.3, Bootstrap 3.3.x CSS (not the JS). There's an animated GIF included.

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label class="control-label">Delivery</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <!-- (Delivery) Field -->
                <select class="form-control"
                        data-ng-options="delivery.value as delivery.name for delivery in options.deliveryOptions"
                        data-ng-model="lineItemSegment.deliveryType"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Animated GIF: http://gph.is/1rIY7dC

```
    $scope.options = {};
    $scope.options.deliveryOptions = [
        { name: 'Evenly',              value: 'EVENLY'              },
        { name: 'Frontloaded',         value: 'FRONTLOADED'         },
        { name: 'As fast as possible', value: 'AS_FAST_AS_POSSIBLE' }
    ];
    $scope.options.priorityOptions = [
        { name: 'Normal', value: 8  },
        { name: 'High',   value: 6  }
    ];
```

Comment: Which is the browser? Did you try with another one?

Comment: My wild guess is that you have an event to close it onMouseLeave and when the box shows, it triggers the close. Try using the keyboard to see if it acts the same way to rule that out. It's hard to tell without the ng code.

Comment: @Miro You're right, it doesn't do that with the keyboard. But how's the onMouseLeave getting attached??? What should I be looking for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem. I used bootstrap form-control on select boxes. The flickering is caused by -webkit-transition and transition properties. Fixed by disabling those in my styles:

```
select.form-control {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}
```